# Installing Windows Update 3033929

Tags: linux, windows-7, debian, grub, windows-update

I am using grub as default boot loader for my dual boot laptop (DELL Vostro 3750). My system is currently undergoing a reboot loop (infinite) because of Windows Update 3033929.

As described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3033929):

> Some users cannot install this security update if their computers meet
>   the following conditions: Have a multiple-boot configuration of
>   Windows and various distributions of Linux

A possible solution seems to be:

> To work around that issue, you can either use Windows as the default
>   boot loader

A lot of articles describe how to set Windows as default grub entry upon start but that is entierely different from what is described as possible solution.

So could someone please describe a working solution (step-by-step) to install `Windows Update 3033929` on a dual boot system (grub 1.99-27+deb7u2 with: debian wheezy and windows 7/64bits). Both partitions reside on the same disk, respectively: `sda5` and `sda2`, so I cannot use the solution described [here](http://darkling.poppameth.com/windows-update-kb3033929-update-loop/).

A possible solution which I found online was to remove grub completely, but that seems like an overkill solution (also I would not even know how to re-install it afterward). I would like to also avoid a solution as listed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb3033929-fails-to-install-and-cause-a-minor/4c56d5d5-a66c-4865-8ccb-d36f7c314c33?page=5) where grub boot loader is removed and replaced by `Windows 7's "bootmgr"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this post is pretty old by now, but hopefully this will save people a lot of trouble with this issue if anyone runs into it in the future.

There's a much simpler way to solve this when Windows and Linux are installed on the same disc, rather than going through all the effort listed in the "Hard case" answer (at least, in my experience).

Dual booting Linux (although I can't speak for all distributions, so this may not be true in some cases), on a Windows machine doesn't remove or affect the MBR on the System partition in any way. All it does is make it inactive and rather uses the GRUB boot loader partition as the active partition. So there's absolutely no need in messing with either boot loader, no need to have to rebuild any boot loader, no need for any of that complication. All that needs to be done to install this failed update is:

1. Change the Windows System partition (usually the smallest partition, at 100MB) to active. This can be done through the Disk Management GUI if you can actually get into your Windows system, or you can do it through the Diskpart command prompt utility in repair mode with:

- `diskpart`
- `select disk 0` (or whatever disk number Windows is installed on. You can find out using "list disk" without the quotes)
- `select partition 1` (again, you can find the proper partition number by typing "list part" without quotes. the 100 MB partition is usually the Windows System partition)
- `active` (this will activate the selected partition, subsequently making the GRUB partition inactive, since it will only allow for one active boot partition)
- `exit` and restart the system, it should boot directly into Windows from the Windows boot loader

2. Install the update that caused the issue (usually KB3033929) and reboot Windows. It should install successfully.
3. Reboot into a command prompt and change the active partition back to the GRUB partition (usually no more than a few hundred MB's) similar to how we activated the Windows System boot loader at the start. Make sure you are choosing the correct partition number when doing this. Example of commands:

- `diskpart`
- `select disk 0`
- `select partition 3`
- `active`
- `exit`

4. Reboot the system. It should boot right back into the GRUB loader as it was before, with all of your OS options available. Check your Windows Updates and you'll see that all of your updates are installed successfully and your system should be running properly.

This solution took me less than 2 minutes to complete, and was incredibly simple. I hope it helps out others and saves people some time when running into these troubles.

Comment: Strangely `diskpart` says "the selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks". Also, right clicking in disk utility only shows "Help" but no other options... I think my Manjaro installation might have somehow overwritten the Window partition? But then how am I still able to boot into Windows after all. That's weird.

Answer (score 7):

The article [Windows Update KB3033929 Update Loop](http://darkling.poppameth.com/windows-update-kb3033929-update-loop/) contains the only
two known solutions for this update loop.

Before starting, I suggest taking an image backup of the entire disk
and verifying that you have the proper boot CD or USB required to restore
it in case of catastrophe.
I would suggest in the future to always take such an image backup before
doing Windows Update, and leaving it in manual mode.

**Easy case : Windows is installed on a separate disk**

1. Shutdown the computer and unplug the non-Windows drive, or if this is
   supported by the BIOS then set the boot disk to the one containing Windows.
2. Reboot directly into Windows and install the KB3033929 update.
3. Reboot again to configure the update.
4. Once everything is installed and operating correctly, shutdown the PC and reconnect the Linux drive.
5. Everything should be back to normal on your next reboot.
6. If not, use F8 during Windows boot to boot into Safe mode and
   reset Windows Update to "Notify but let me download",
   or set this update to "Never show", in order to avoid installing it
   until Microsoft finally gets it right.

**Hard case : Both Windows and Linux are installed on same disk**

In this case you must replace the bootloader by that of Windows,
let this update install itself, then return GRUB.
The steps are as follows :

1. Boot from the Windows installation media and choose the
   Command Prompt repair option.
2. Type the following and press Enter:

`Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`

Then type and press Enter:

`Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

3. Reboot straight into Windows (Grub is no longer there).
4. Install the problematic update and get Windows up and running correctly.
5. To get GRUB back, boot computer into a live Linux CD or USB
   and choose to "try" the OS.
6. Find out on which partition Linux is installed,
   perhaps by using the Gparted utility to find the root "/" partition.
   Let’s assume this is on sda1.
7. To mount that partition. Open a terminal and type and press Enter:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

8. Reinstall grub with the following command:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda –root-directory=/mnt`

9. Remove the installation media and reboot.
   The Grub bootloader will only show the Linux installation.
10. To fix this, boot to the Linux desktop, open a terminal and run this command for it to pick up all available OS on the machine:

`sudo update-grub`

11. Reboot and you should now have Grub functioning and your Windows install as a bootable option.
12. If the above did not work for you, try the alternate method
    in the article
    [Removing Linux Grub & Restoring Windows 7 Boot GUI](http://lukeaddison.com/removing-linux-grub-restoring-windows-7-boot-gui/).
    This article might also be useful :
    [How to repair, adapt or remove the Grub boot loader](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub).
13. If none of the above worked, restore the backup disk image and, sorry,
    you are now back to square one.

Comment: Having a multi-boot zoo with a couple of Linux distributions and at least two active Win partitions, I had the hard++ version: Using either `cfdisk` (on Linux) or `diskpart` (with Windows recovery medium) make sure you only have **ONE** active Windows partition, otherwise `BootRec.exe /FixBoot` may fail (with sth like "invalid filesystem"). Afterwards use `bootsect.exe /nt60 C: /mbr /force`, then standard "Startup repair" option from the Windows revovery medium. Worked for me (after many failed tries).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I ran into this issue as well after dualbooting Manjaro Linux. Windows keeps prompting me to restart but the update is not installed. I tried to mark partition as "active" but it didn't work.

However, eventually an error code `0x80070bc2` appeared in Windows Update. I followed a solution listed in Microsoft Community and ran

```
SC config wuauserv start= auto
SC config bits start= auto
SC config cryptsvc start= auto
SC config trustedinstaller start= auto
```

in cmd as admin.

Then, Windows update was able to proceed but two further errors arose:  `0x8007045b` and `0x80070490`.

I then ran:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

and everything was finally fine.

The first command took a while to run and seemed to be stuck at 94.4%. But after a while it got through.

I’ll just leave what I encountered here in case anybody runs into the same issue in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to remove grub. Just use gparted live (gparted.org) and remove the boot flag from Linux partition (in case you have a separated boot partition remove the boot flag from it) and attribute the boot flag to Windows partition.
Reboot the PC (it will boot in Window), install the update (the PC will need a reboot).
Shutdown the PC, and reboot it with gparted live and undo the changed of boot flag.

Comment: In reality, I am! When you remove the boot flag from the Linux boot partition and attribute it to the Windows partition, the next boot process will not use the grub but will boot directly from the Windows partition. There is one catch to this! If you installed Linux and Windows in the same partition you will need to rebuild the Windows MBR using a windows recovery or installation disk. Then this  will require a reinstallation of grub. The same is needed if the Linux boot was installed on the MBR.

Comment: If you have anything extra to add, re-edit your previous answer and append there, instead of posting another answer with additional comment.